# Can I run a miner on the same computer as a P2Pool node?

Tags: miner-configuration, p2pool

I have a P2Pool node running as a VM on my computer.  When I tried to mine on the locally hosted node, the console for the miner was spammed with accepted shares.  When I connect to a remote node, everything seems normal, and not so spammy.

Is it possible to set my miner to mine on the locally hosted node, or will I have to point my miner to a different node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a local node with no issue.  The `p2pool` instance will eventually increase the difficulty of the shares it asks of the miner if it is getting too many of them. 99% of those "accepted" shares are simply faked to keep the mining client happy anyway, the current share difficulty of the `p2pool` network is over 500k.

Comment: Thanks, I realized that that flood of accepted shares is my node getting its difficulty straight.